# Set up one meteor server to subscribe to another meteor server?

Tags: meteor, distributed

Meteor is mostly described as a client-server architecture, with the client usually being a browser or even native (mobile) application facing the user.

**Is it, in contrast, a feasible approach to set up one meteor server to subscribe to another meteor server as a client?**

Use case is similar to the distributed approach of http://diasporaproject.org/, i.e. a distributed but connected server ("pods") architecture.

Comment: **Update:** This seems to be a valid concept, but not yet available in the current version. From http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_connect:
**In this release, Meteor.connect can only be called on the client.
Servers can not yet connect to other servers.**

Comment: you can actually post that update as an answer to your own question, which will allow you to accept it and also help future visitors :)

Comment: I wonder if this is still true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a valid concept, but not yet available in the current version. From docs.meteor.com/#meteor_connect: **In this release, Meteor.connect can only be called on the client. Servers can not yet connect to other servers.**

*Thanks Rahul for helping a stackoverflow newbie!*